# Two different domain A and B both on separate server, how to get session created on A get into B server, same B to A

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

Two different domain A and B both on separate server, how to get  session  created on A get into B server, same B to A

My application use laravel 5.2 web not api base structure

Secure way to get that session is my goal.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a database session driver and then define the same database connection for both applications.

Answer (score 0):

To do so, you need to not only 1. use a shared session driver (like database or cache) but you also 2. need to implement cross domain session IDs.

Since the session cookie can not be passed around between 2 domains (can be done only on sub-domains of the same domain), you need to append the session ID to all your requests.

**Note for Security Purposes:** Be careful to check both the IP address and the session ID to prevent people from guessing someone elses SessionID and thus logging in as another person

The detailed answer to this question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41749828/7377984